# Should I pick fonts or colors first for my design?

Tags: fonts, color-theory

I always struggle to choose what to pick first, fonts or colors?

This applies to website, brochures, pretty much anything that uses both.

Any advice on this? Couldn't find anything on Google...!

Comment: *Must* you pick a font or color first, just to be stuck with it forever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is a matter of perspective. The choice is highly influenced by a ton of variables say, the nature of your client, their budget, time-frame of the project and sometimes on the designer's character. But in most cases, it is always the colors to think about before you consider the font. Note that the visual quality of the font will be defined by its color and the background on which it sits.

From the client perspective, even most of them who know little about fonts will definitely know what color they want or really don't want to see in their designs. And as a designer, you end up choosing for them a set of appropriate fonts(free or premium) and later present this for choice selection.

However if its an open project, say a personal project, you might have your work defined in grey scale, balanced on white space and the typography before you start testing it against some possible color combinations.

Some brands, more so those with a line of products might have a strict defined font on which you have to build your design.

From my perspective, since it's "Color that the eye notices first", I start most of my designs based on a defined color pallet and shades of grey then choose a great font that I like. Later make iterations to that font depending on the license options and client taste.

Comment: Hello iamcastelli and thanks for contributing. If you're starting an answer with "This question is a matter of perspective" you should consider flagging it as opinion based instead of answering it. We have standards set for questions in order to keep the question quality high

Comment: Thanks for the insight @ZachSaucier! One question though, if you flag a question, does that imply you shouldn't throw any opinion to it?

Comment: It's best not to. See [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133552/2154850) :)

Comment: It's a great answer. I find it highly annoying that Stack Excange keeps policing all posts according to "quality" standards. And they are  loosing a lot of members because of it. They should slack off on these controls.

Comment: @BrunoVincent: low quality questions attract low quality answers, so it's weird that you acknowledge this is a good answer. If the high quality level of questions and answers annoys you, best to take it to [meta].

Comment: The eye notices value (lights and darks) and contrast first. Then pattern and shapes.